# I want to create a function that shows the full name and email of the selected option

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function afficher() / print() that shows the name and email of the selected option

```js
// ajouter() = add()
// supprimer() = delete()
// afficher() = print()

function ajouter() {

  let fullName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  let mail = document.getElementById("email").value;

  myList = [];
  myList.push({
    name: fullName,
    email: mail
  })

  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += '<option>' + fullName + '</option>' + '<br>';
}

function supprimer() {
  let del = document.getElementById("list");
  del.remove(del.selectedIndex);
}


//     function afficher(){

//     let show = document.getElementById("list")
//     let showName = myList[show.selectedIndex].name,
//         showEmail = myList[show.selectedIndex].email;

//     alert("Hello " + showName + " Your email is : " + showEmail);

// }
```

```html
<form action="">
  <br><br>
  <label for="name">Full name : <input id="name" type="text"></label><br><br>
  <label for="email">Email : <input id="email" type="email"></label><br><br><br>

  <button type="button" onclick="ajouter()">Ajouter</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="supprimer()">Supprimer</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="afficher()">Afficher l'addresse</button>
  <br><br>
  <select name="names-list" id="list" size="5" style="width: 200px;">

  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: plase update your question to include code instead of pictures of code. it make it more easy to answer

Comment: I had problems when I tried to put the code in the text field that's why I uploaded them as images

Comment: Just click [edit], then the `[<>]` snippet editor and fill the code in the correct panels

Comment: You want to move myList = [] outside the function

Comment: yes i want to move myList outside the function so as to get the values from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move myList = [] outside the functions

Here is a fully working version

Uncomment the parts with localStorage to save the list

```js
const myListString = null// localStorage.getItem("list");
const myList = myListString ? JSON.parse(myListString) : [];
const list = document.getElementById("list");


function ajouter() {

  let fullName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  let mail = document.getElementById("email").value;

  myList.push({
    name: fullName,
    email: mail
  })
  list.add(new Option(fullName));
  // localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(myList))
}

function supprimer() {
  const fullName =  document.getElementById("name").value;
  const idx = myList.findIndex(item => item.name === fullName)
  if (idx !=-1) {
    myList.splice(idx,1)
    list.options[idx].remove()
  }
}

function afficher() { 
  const idx = list.selectedIndex;
  const person = myList[idx]
  alert("Hello " + person.name + " Your email is : " + person.email);
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <br><br>
  <label for="name">Full name : <input id="name" type="text"></label><br><br>
  <label for="email">Email : <input id="email" type="email"></label><br><br><br>

  <button type="button" onclick="ajouter()">Ajouter</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="supprimer()">Supprimer</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="afficher()">Afficher l'addresse</button>
  <br><br>
  <select name="names-list" id="list" size="5" style="width: 200px;">
  </select>
</form>
```